# Detect emoji in Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, emoji, botframework

I am developing a bot with the Bot Framework. When receiving a message I need to detect emojis sent in the incoming message.

I was thinking of using a regex to do this but I am not able to. The problem is that different channels send the emoji differently to the bot. I have registered a listener to the 'receive' event and took a look at the text provided for different channels sending the same smile emoji:

- Slack: `:smile:`
- Skype: `<ss type="smile">:)<ss>`
- Emulator:

I need to identify which emoji I am receiving and act accrodingly. What I ideally would like is to receive the unicode character for the emoji no matter what channel I am using. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: You can get the emoji unicode code points from http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: how does it apply to the question above? I'm asking because I'm trying to solve the same

Answer (score 2):

I think you can inspect the user response with middleware and then convert (based on the channel your message was sent) to any universal emoji.

In your sample:

- Slack: :smile:
- Skype: :)
- Emulator:

Your result may be an: ":)". It can be extremely complex to cover all the emojis from all the channels supported.

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Please send an emoji...');
    },
    function (session, result) {
        console.log(result.response);
    }
]);

const convertEmoji = (event) => {
    if (event.source === "skype") {
        if (/laugh/g.test(event.text)) {
            event.text = ':D';
        }
    }
};

bot.use({
    receive: function (event, next) {
        convertEmoji(event);
        next();
    }
});
```

Take in consideration that this will apply to all messages user sent to bot.